# Youtube json feed returning all results

Tags: javascript, json, youtube, feed

I am currently calling a youtube playlist using:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=USERNAME&v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=function

I was just wondering if there was a way to pull through all of the videos on my feed, I have around 250 videos and its only returning 25... :-/

Any help would be much appreciated...thanks!

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters.html#max-resultssp

25 is the default number of items that are returned.
Use `max-results=nn` to request up to 50 items.

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=USERNAME&v=2&max-results=50&alt=jsonc&callback=function